# How to set a few variables in ALL my .js files when app first loads? I need these to proportion all my screen sizes before the user sees

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to set ~10 variables relating to screen sizes BEFORE the user sees all the screens in the app. I can do this in the `AppLoadingScreen.js` (as that is universal in terms of size). I have the following function and switch statement (but i don't know how exactly to run it). Once they're set, i want to ensure all the screens (or .js files) have these variables set and ready to go.

```
export function whichScreen() {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('window');

  if ((dim.width === 375 )){
    return 0;
  }
  else if((dim.width === 414)){
    return 1;
  }
  else if((dim.width === 484 )){
    return 2;
  }
  else if((dim.width === 578 )){
    return 3;
  }
}


getScreenParams=()=>{

  let size = this.whichScreen();

  switch(size) {

      case 0:
        this.setState({ marginforcontainer: 2, marginforSignIn: 5, ....}) //Don't even know which class to put the state variables in?
        break;

      case 1:
        this.setState({ marginforcontainer: 6, marginforSignIn: 7, ....}) //Don't even know which class to put the state variables in?
        break;

      case 2:
        this.setState({ marginforcontainer: 8, marginforSignIn: 6, ....}) //Don't even know which class to put the state variables in?
        break;

      case 3:
        this.setState({ marginforcontainer: 4, marginforSignIn: 1, ....}) //Don't even know which class to put the state variables in?
        break;

      default:

    }
  }
```

I dont want to have to run the getScreenParams() function EVERY TIME a user moves onto each of the screens, thats just awful. Also putting them in AsyncStorage and calling a getItem() from AsyncStorage each time is expensive.

How do i run this once while the app is loading and set the variables i need??

Comment: your case values are are a string e.g. `'1'`. they need to be a number e.g. `1`, without the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent wrapper component and inside you can render the routes. Route change will only re render the components within it. Not outside of it. So your `getScreenParams()` won't get called multiple times.

```
export class WrapperComponent() {
  componentDidMount() {
       getScreenParams(); 
  }

  render() {
    <React.Fragment>
     <Router>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/about">
           <About dimensions={marginforcontainer}/>
         </Route>
         <Route path="/sign-in" dimensions={marginforSignIn}>
           <Users />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/">
           <Home dimensions={marginforcontainer}/>
         </Route>
       </Switch>
     </Router
   <React.Fragment>
  }
}


// Usage in app.js or any other main component.
const {marginforcontainer, marginforSignIn} = this.state;

<WrapperComponent>
```

Or instead of returning the case what you can do is just return an Object

```
export function whichScreen() {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('window');

  if ((dim.width === 375 )){
    return { marginforcontainer: 2, marginforSignIn: 5, ....};
  }

  else if((dim.width === 414)){
    return { marginforcontainer: 6, marginforSignIn: 7, ....};
  }
}
```

then each component `{ marginforcontainer, marginforSignIn} = this.whichScreen();` You're not changing any state by doing this. Just accessing the params from global/window.